# Handle Copy & Paste (Clipboard) in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, clipboard, copy-paste

If I want to access the clipboard with MVVM how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SL 4 now supports text clipboard operations. This is transparent in OOB mode and requires user confirmation if not in OOB mode.

You can use `Clipboard.GetText()` in your view models and commands to retrieve the text content available in the clipboard.

Comment: I am actually asking in a MVVM app, where should clipboard logic go. Is accessing the Clipboard from my ViewModel be a good idea?

Comment: Do you mean 'as opposed to doing it in the XAML code behind'? If so, I believe the answer is no. To me it seems legitimate the view model is aware of the clipboard.

Answer (score 5):

While you certainly can do things like `Clipboard.SetText` and `Clipboard.GetText` in your VM, if you are an MVVM purist (like me), then I would recommend creating a ClipboardService (with an appropriate interface, so you can mock it in unit tests).  Something like the following:

```
using System.Windows;

public class ClipboardService : IClipboardService
{
    public void SetText(string value)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(value);
    }

    public string GetText()
    {
        return Clipboard.GetText();
    }
}
```

Then you can reference it as a property in your VM like so:

```
public IClipboardService ClipboardService { get; set; }
```

And either set it directly as a property or include it in your constructor:

```
public FooViewModel(IClipboardService service) {
    ClipboardService = service;
}
```

And when you need it, instead of calling Clipboard.SetText directly, you can use ClipboardService.SetText instead.  And you can (as mentioned before) mock it in unit tests.  So, if you use Moq (like I do), you could have something like:

```
Mock<IClipboardService> clipMock = new Mock<IClipboardService>();
clipMock.Setup(mock => mock.GetText(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns("Foo");
```

And instantiate your VM like so:

```
var fooVm = new FooViewModel(clipMock.Object);
```

And so on.

I realize this is an ancient post, but I was looking for some best practices on Clipboards and MVVM, made my own decision while reading this post and decided to share.  Hope somebody finds it useful.  :-)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Why do we need to implement that interface? How does it help with unit testing?

Comment: Glad you asked.  If the method you are testing makes a call to the clipboard that could potentially affect the outcome of the test, you don't want to be worried about anything else potentially messing with the contents of the clipboard while the test is running.  By wrapping that in a service that implements an interface, you can control exactly what is in your "clipboard" during your unit tests, because you're more interested in testing what the VM does with the clipboard data than the actual clipboard functionality itself (which, presumably works as it's a part of the .NET Framework).  HTH!